# Org Babel Redirect stderr (-c option requires an argument)

Tags: org-babel

Reading about how to redirect [stderr](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/01/04/Redirecting-stderr-in-org-mode-shell-blocks/), but it does not work for me.

```
$ cat bash-redir-stderr.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
bash $1
} 2>&1
```

I get:

```
bash: -c: option requires an argument
```

..no matter what I try. If I set it back

```
;original value
(setq shell-file-name "/run/current-system/sw/bin/bash")
```

it works fine again.

But how do I capture `stderr` in the RESULTS envelope, so that it doesn't open a new buffer to display it?

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for an explanation of the above behavior or are you looking for a way to capture `stderr` from your Org babel shell code block? Or maybe something else?

Comment: I want to capture stderr in the RESULTS envelope, so that it doesn't open a new buffer to display stderr;)

Comment: I edited your question to actually ask the question you wanted to ask from the above comment. Please try to make questions self-contained. In particular, do not add material information in a comment: *edit the question and add the information to it instead*.

Answer (score 0):

The last paragraph of John Kitchin's post that you linked to in your question shows a way to capture `stderr` from your shell blocks:

```
Achim Gratz suggested this simpler approach that does not involve
any external scripts. The : at the end is important!

exec 2>&1
echo "testing stdout" >&1
echo "testing stderr" >&2
date -g
:
```

Basically, `exec 2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout` for any subsequent commands in the shell block, and the `:` at the end is a do-nothing command that exits with a success (0) status; the reason for that is that earlier versions of Org babel would produce no output if the command failed (which e.g. `date -g` does) - current versions of Org mode do not do that, so the `:` at the end may or may not be necessary. But it doesn't hurt, so I include it in what follows to allow older versions to work the same way.

You can automate the process by adding [`:prologue` and `:epilogue` headers to a code block](https://orgmode.org/manual/Environment-of-a-Code-Block.html) - see the last subsection of that section. These headers are not provided by every `babel` language processor, but they *are* provided by the `shell` processor:

```org
#+begin_src shell :prologue "exec 2>&1" :epilogue ":" :results drawer
echo "testing stdout" >&1
echo "testing stderr" >&2
date -g
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
testing stdout
testing stderr
date: invalid option -- 'g'
Try 'date --help' for more information.
:end:
```

And of course, instead of adding those headers to every code block, you can define [header arguments in Org mode properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html) to make them apply to every `shell` block in the file:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:shell :prologue "exec 2>&1" :epilogue ":" :results drawer
```

or in a section of the file:

```
* Some section
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:shell: :prologue "exec 2>&1" :epilogue ":" :results drawer
:END:

  #+begin_src shell
    echo "testing stdout" >&1
    echo "testing stderr" >&2
    date -g
  #+end_src
```